# Replacing day in date with last day of month

Tags: python, date, replace

I've got a dataframe with column 'date', containing yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.
Python automatically assigned first day of every quarterly month, but I want last day of same month.

I've tried:

```
cr_ind_ml_new = cr_ind_ml.replace(to_replace= '07-01', value='07-31', regex=True)
```

and

```
cr_ind_ml.replace('07-01', '07-31', inplace= True)
```

without any success.

sample of df:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1990-07-01 00:00:00 | 46.7 |
| 1990-10-01 00:00:00 | 54.2 |
| 1991-01-01 00:00:00 | 38.6 |
| 1991-04-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1991-07-01 00:00:00 | 18.6 |

I want:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1990-07-31 00:00:00 | 46.7 |
| 1990-10-30 00:00:00 | 54.2 |
| 1991-01-31 00:00:00 | 38.6 |
| 1991-04-30 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1991-07-31 00:00:00 | 18.6 |

Does anyone have thoughts?

Comment: what type does the column contains ? datetime or str ? Also explain the "without any success"

Comment: string. I haven't used datetime at all.
I don't get any errors. In example 1 the new df is created but looks the same as before. In example 2, nothin happens to dataframe

Comment: You said that your column contains year-month-day, but in the code you provide month-day. What values do you really have in your dataframe?

Comment: Apart from the inconsistency in the information you provide: There's a difference between `.replace` and `.str.replace` that might be relevant. Anyways, it would probably be better to cast the strings into `datetime` objects and then do the switch.

Comment: @ZygD Yes, the dataframe has ‘yyyy-mm-dd 00.00’, where the rows provided are quarterly data for every year (e.g. 1990-07-01, 2002-04-01). in these examples, want to replace all  ‘07-01’ with ‘07-31’ and all ‘04-01’ with  ‘04-01’ (I.e. last day of that month for every year in data frame)

Comment: @Timus Ok, thanks! How would I go about changing to timedate and then replacing all first days to last days of month?

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71979649/edit) a sample of the strings into the question (exactly as they appear in your dataframe).

Comment: @Timus Yes, absolutely. That will likely make it easier for you to understand my aim.
Please see above.

Comment: Is `cr_ind_ml` the entire dataframe? What do you get when you do `print(cr_ind_ml['date'].dtype)`?

Comment: If they're strings then you want to do `df['date'].str.replace(...)`, which replaces _in each string_. `df['date'].replace(...)` replaces when _whole values_ match the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `df`

```
                  date  value
0  1990-07-01 00:00:00   46.7
1  1990-10-01 00:00:00   54.2
2  1991-01-01 00:00:00   38.6
3  1991-04-01 00:00:00   20.0
4  1991-07-01 00:00:00   18.6
```

has a column `date` with strings, then you can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the [`MonthEnd()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) offset to do

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
```

which gives you

```
        date  value
0 1990-07-31   46.7
1 1990-10-31   54.2
2 1991-01-31   38.6
3 1991-04-30   20.0
4 1991-07-31   18.6
```

But: The elements of `date` are now of type `datetime`. If the items in `date` have already type `datetime`, then you don't need the `pd.to_datetime()` part - just adding the offset is enough.

If you want the expected output as strings, then this (starting from the original)

```
df['date'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

gives you

```
                 date  value
0  1990-07-31 00:00:00   46.7
1  1990-10-31 00:00:00   54.2
2  1991-01-31 00:00:00   38.6
3  1991-04-30 00:00:00   20.0
4  1991-07-31 00:00:00   18.6
```

Comment: Wow, options 1 worked like a charm! 
Thanks you so much for taking the time to help me.